# Overriding default entry point in ServerHttpSecurity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

I use the following ServerHttpSecurity chain:

```kotlin
    @Bean
    fun springSecurityFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
        http
            // ..filters

            .authorizeExchange().anyExchange()
            .access(CustomHaveAnyAuthority())

            // authentication
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt()
            .authenticationManager(CustomAuthenticationService())
        return http.build()
    }
```

However in newer Spring Security 5.5.0 (upgrade from 5.3.3.RELEASE) there is a fallback upon requesting endpoints without auth to **BearerTokenServerAuthenticationEntryPoint** instead of **HttpBasicServerAuthenticationEntryPoint**.

How can I override this behaviour? I tried to resort methods above, but didn't work.

Logs from application:

```
2021-06-02 11:50:43,206 [boundedElastic-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.a.DelegatingReactiveAuthorizationManager - Checking authorization on '/endpoint' using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthorityReactiveAuthorizationManager@73302f30
2021-06-02 11:50:43,216 [boundedElastic-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.authorization.AuthorizationWebFilter - Authorization failed: Access Denied
2021-06-02 11:50:43,220 [boundedElastic-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.c.WebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext found in WebSession: 'org.springframework.web.server.session.InMemoryWebSessionStore$InMemoryWebSession@921515f'
2021-06-02 11:50:43,221 [boundedElastic-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.DelegatingServerAuthenticationEntryPoint - Trying to match using OrServerWebExchangeMatcher{matchers=[org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$HttpBasicSpec$$Lambda$1073/0x0000000100b00040@73874030, AndServerWebExchangeMatcher{matchers=[NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher{matcher=MediaTypeRequestMatcher [matchingMediaTypes=[text/html], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]}, MediaTypeRequestMatcher [matchingMediaTypes=[application/atom+xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/json, application/octet-stream, application/xml, multipart/form-data, text/xml], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]}]}
2021-06-02 11:50:43,221 [boundedElastic-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.util.matcher.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher - Trying to match using org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$HttpBasicSpec$$Lambda$1073/0x0000000100b00040@73874030
2021-06-02 11:50:43,222 [boundedElastic-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.util.matcher.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher - Trying to match using AndServerWebExchangeMatcher{matchers=[NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher{matcher=MediaTypeRequestMatcher [matchingMediaTypes=[text/html], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]}, MediaTypeRequestMatcher [matchingMediaTypes=[application/atom+xml, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/json, application/octet-stream, application/xml, multipart/form-data, text/xml], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]]}
2021-06-02 11:50:43,227 [boundedElastic-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.util.matcher.AndServerWebExchangeMatcher - Trying to match using NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher{matcher=MediaTypeRequestMatcher [matchingMediaTypes=[text/html], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[]]}
2021-06-02 11:50:43,227 [boundedElastic-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.u.m.MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher - httpRequestMediaTypes=[text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
2021-06-02 11:50:43,227 [boundedElastic-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.u.m.MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher - Processing text/html
2021-06-02 11:50:43,227 [boundedElastic-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.u.m.MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher - text/html .isCompatibleWith text/html = true
2021-06-02 11:50:43,228 [boundedElastic-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.u.m.NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher - matches = false
2021-06-02 11:50:43,228 [boundedElastic-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.util.matcher.AndServerWebExchangeMatcher - Did not match
2021-06-02 11:50:43,228 [boundedElastic-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.util.matcher.OrServerWebExchangeMatcher - No matches found
2021-06-02 11:50:43,229 [boundedElastic-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.DelegatingServerAuthenticationEntryPoint - Trying to match using org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationConverterServerWebExchangeMatcher@21307a04
2021-06-02 11:50:43,229 [boundedElastic-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.DelegatingServerAuthenticationEntryPoint - No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.server.BearerTokenServerAuthenticationEntryPoint@24d2ea8a
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own way to handle the exceptions, like this:

```kotlin
@Bean
fun springSecurityFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
    http
        .authorizeExchange().anyExchange()
        .access(CustomHaveAnyAuthority())
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt()
        .authenticationManager(CustomAuthenticationService())
        .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(HttpBasicServerAuthenticationEntryPoint())
    return http.build()
}
```

Comment: Managed to get it work like this: ***.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(HttpBasicServerAuthenticationEntryPoint())***, are there any drawbacks using this approach?

Comment: No, actually I used the non-reactive class for it, I'm gonna update my answer. Didn't notice :)